# How do I replace values within a data frame with a string in R?

Tags: string, r, replace, na

short version:  How do I replace values within a data frame with a string found within another data frame?

longer version: I'm a biologist working with many species of bees. I have a data set with many thousands of bees.  Each row has a unique bee ID # along with all the relevant info about that specimen (data of capture, GPS location, etc).  The species information for each bee has not been entered because it takes a long time to ID them. When IDing, I end up with boxes of hundred of bees, all of the same species.  I enter these into a separate data frame. I am trying to write code that will update the original data file with species information (family, genus, species, sex, etc) as I ID the bees. Currently, in the original data file, the species info is blank and is interpreted as NA within R.  I want to have R find all unique bee ID #'s and fill in the species info, but I am having trouble figuring out how to replace the NA values with a string (e.g. "Andrenidae")

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
rawData<-data.frame(beeID=c(1:20),family=rep(NA,20))
speciesInfo<-data.frame(beeID=seq(1,20,3),family=rep("Andrenidae",7))

rawData[rawData$beeID == 4,"family"]  <- speciesInfo[speciesInfo$beeID == 4,"family"]
```

So, I am replacing things as I want, but with a number rather than the family name (a string).  What I would eventually like to do is write a little loop to add in all the species info, e.g.:

```
for (i in speciesInfo$beeID){
  rawData[rawData$beeID == i,"family"]  <- speciesInfo[speciesInfo$beeID == i,"family"]
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Cheers,

Zak

EDIT:

I just noticed that the first two methods below add a new column each time, which would cause problems if I needed to add species info multiple times (which I typically do). For example:

```
rawData<-data.frame(beeID=c(1:20),family=rep(NA,20))
Andrenidae<-data.frame(beeID=seq(1,20,3),family=rep("Andrenidae",7))
Halictidae<-data.frame(beeID=seq(1,20,3)+1,family=rep("Halictidae",7))

# using join
library(plyr)
rawData <- join(rawData, Andrenidae, by = "beeID", type = "left")
rawData <- join(rawData, Halictidae, by = "beeID", type = "left")

# using merge
rawData <- merge(x=rawData,y=Andrenidae,by='beeID',all.x=T,all.y=F)
rawData <- merge(x=rawData,y=Halictidae,by='beeID',all.x=T,all.y=F)
```

Is there a way to either collapse the columns so that I have one, unified data frame?  Or a way to update the rawData rather than adding a new column each time?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function I think will work for you. This uses `match` to find and index of values in your annotation dataframe, and then replaces the values in the rawData.

```
replaceID <- function(to,from,mergeBy,values){
  x <- match(from[,mergeBy],to[,mergeBy])
  to[,values][x] <- as.character(from[,values])
  return(to)
}
> rawData <- replaceID(rawData,Halictidae,"beeID","family")
> rawData
   beeID     family
1      1       <NA>
2      2 Halictidae
3      3       <NA>
4      4       <NA>
5      5 Halictidae
6      6       <NA>
7      7       <NA>
8      8 Halictidae
9      9       <NA>
10    10       <NA>
11    11 Halictidae
12    12       <NA>
13    13       <NA>
14    14 Halictidae
15    15       <NA>
16    16       <NA>
17    17 Halictidae
18    18       <NA>
19    19       <NA>
20    20 Halictidae
```

Comment: This is perfect, it does exactly what I had initially envisioned.  Thank you for the help!  Cheers,  Zak

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `?join` in package `plyr`

```
    library(plyr)
#Adding family ahead of time was unnecessary so I'll remove it alongside the join.
join(rawData, speciesInfo, by = "beeID", type = "left")[,-2]
   beeID     family
1      1 Andrenidae
2      2       <NA>
3      3       <NA>
4      4 Andrenidae
5      5       <NA>
6      6       <NA>
7      7 Andrenidae
8      8       <NA>
9      9       <NA>
10    10 Andrenidae
11    11       <NA>
12    12       <NA>
13    13 Andrenidae
14    14       <NA>
15    15       <NA>
16    16 Andrenidae
17    17       <NA>
18    18       <NA>
19    19 Andrenidae
20    20       <NA>
```

## Update

```
# If you anticipate adding new species over time, 
# simply rbind those into a single reference data.frame to merge with your rawData. 
# Like so:
library(plyr)
rawData <- join(rawData, rbind(Andrenidae, Halictidae), by = "beeID", type = "left")

# To keep you code clean, you could do this step ahead of time
species_list <- rbind(Andrenidae, Halictidae)
rawData <- join(rawData, species_list, by = "beeID", type = "left")
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how to include code in a reply, so I edited my original question with a follow up question. I've always been a lurker, so I have yet to get the hang of contributing. Thanks again for any and all help!

Comment: Glad you edited your question (that's how SO is supposed to work, i.e., clarify and improve your question based on the answers). The edited answer should address your new question. If your dataset gets significantly larger, there are more powerful solutions for this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [merge](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/merge.html) function, e.g. :

```
rawData <- data.frame(beeID=c(1:20),family=rep(NA,20))
speciesInfo <- data.frame(beeID=seq(1,20,3),
                          family=c(rep('Halictidae',4), rep("Andrenidae",3)))

merged <- merge(x=rawData,y=speciesInfo,by='beeID',all.x=T,all.y=F)
merged$family.x <- NULL # remove the family.x column
names(merged) <- c('beeID','family') # rename the columns
```

**N.B.**

It is not necessary to initialize `rawData` with the `family`column.
Merge function will add it automatically, e.g. :

```
rawData <- data.frame(beeID=c(1:20))
speciesInfo <- data.frame(beeID=seq(1,20,3),
                          family=c(rep('Halictidae',4), rep("Andrenidae",3)))

merged <- merge(x=rawData,y=speciesInfo,by='beeID',all.x=T,all.y=F)

> merged
   beeID     family
1      1 Halictidae
2      2       <NA>
3      3       <NA>
4      4 Halictidae
5      5       <NA>
6      6       <NA>
7      7 Halictidae
8      8       <NA>
9      9       <NA>
10    10 Halictidae
11    11       <NA>
12    12       <NA>
13    13 Andrenidae
14    14       <NA>
15    15       <NA>
16    16 Andrenidae
17    17       <NA>
18    18       <NA>
19    19 Andrenidae
20    20       <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` solution that will be memory and time efficient.

- Note that you need to have `stringsAsFactors = F` for rbindlist (a super-fast version of do.call(rbind,list) / rbind)
- I've added another column as dummy data to the `rawData` object and removed family.

Create the data -

```
rawData <- data.frame(beeID = c(1:20), other_stuff = sample(letters, 20), stringsAsFactors = F)
Andrenidae <- data.frame(beeID = seq(1, 20, 3), family = rep("Andrenidae", 7), stringsAsFactors = F)
Halictidae <- data.frame(beeID = seq(1, 20 , 3)+  1, family = rep("Halictidae", 7), stringsAsFactors = F)
library(data.table)
# convert to data.table
rawDT <- as.data.table(rawData)
# combine the list of Species-specific data.frames into a large data.table
speciesInfo <- rbindlist(list(Andrenidae, Halictidae))
# set the keys, to allow efficient use of data.table and its merging 
# abilities. The keys are the same for both 
setkeyv(rawDT, 'beeID')
setkeyv(speciesInfo, 'beeID')
# merge by key 
speciesInfo[rawDT, nomatch = NA]
## beeID     family other_stuff
## 1:     1 Andrenidae           s
## 2:     2 Halictidae           x
## 3:     3         NA           i
## 4:     4 Andrenidae           e
## 5:     5 Halictidae           v
## 6:     6         NA           q
## 7:     7 Andrenidae           w
## 8:     8 Halictidae           c
## 9:     9         NA           u
## 10:    10 Andrenidae           z
## 11:    11 Halictidae           y
## 12:    12         NA           a
## 13:    13 Andrenidae           l
## 14:    14 Halictidae           r
## 15:    15         NA           h
## 16:    16 Andrenidae           o
## 17:    17 Halictidae           n
## 18:    18         NA           g
## 19:    19 Andrenidae           p
## 20:    20 Halictidae           m
```

or

```
rawDT[speciesInfo]

##    beeID other_stuff     family
## 1:     1           s Andrenidae
## 2:     2           x Halictidae
## 3:     4           e Andrenidae
## 4:     5           v Halictidae
## 5:     7           w Andrenidae
## 6:     8           c Halictidae
## 7:    10           z Andrenidae
## 8:    11           y Halictidae
## 9:    13           l Andrenidae
## 10:   14           r Halictidae
## 11:   16           o Andrenidae
## 12:   17           n Halictidae
## 13:   19           p Andrenidae
## 14:   20           m Halictidae
```

Which ever is the data you are interested in